# how to fetch corresponding value from json based on a if condition in xslt

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I have a input json given below.

```
[
    {
        "ns2:Field": [
            {
                "_": "138045",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dID"
                }
            },
            {
                "_": "FinExmExportERToAPJobDef_405605",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dDocTitle"
                }
            },
            {
                "_": "Document",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dDocType"
                }
            }
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "ns2:Field": [
            {
                "_": "FinExmExportERToAPJobDef_4056456",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dDocTitle"
                }
            },
            {
                "_": "138078",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dID"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "_": "Document",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dDocType"
                }
            }
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "ns2:Field": [
            {
                "_": "138085",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dID"
                }
            },
            {
                "_": "FinExmExportERToAPJobDef_4056056",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dDocTitle"
                }
            },
            {
                "_": "Document",
                "$": {
                    "name": "dDocType"
                }
            }
            
        ]
    }
]
```

From this json i want a array of all the DID value.
My sample output is

```
[138045, 138078, 138085]
```

How can i create this array from input json. I have tried to use choose, when and even xslt if both are giving me empty output. below is the xslt i have tried

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" expand-text="yes" > 
    <xsl:param name="input"/> 
    <xsl:output method="text"/> 
    
    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template"> 
        <xsl:variable name="input-as-xml" select="json-to-xml($input)"/> 
        <xsl:variable name="transformed-xml" as="element(array)"> 
            <array>
                <xsl:for-each select='$input-as-xml//array[@key="ns2:Field"]'>
                   <map>
                       <string key="did">
                       <xsl:choose>
                           <xsl:when test="//map[@key='$']/string[@key='name'] = 'dID'">
                               <xsl:value-of select="./string[@key='_']"/>
                           </xsl:when>
                       </xsl:choose>
                       
                       </string>
                    
                        
                   </map>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </array>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml)"/> </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As i was unable to create the array i though of putting the values of each did in the did key value pair.
but still i am not getting its value. can some one explain me how can i traverse the json to get all the did values.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to convert it to XML first, you can do

```
array{?*?('ns2:Field')?*[?('$')?name='dID']?_}
```

Tested with Saxon 10: with the JSON output method this produces

```
["138045","138078","138085"]
```

The tricky part of this, of course, is debugging. I didn't get it right first time! It helps to know that you can wrap a call on trace() around any part of the expression to get a partial result. In my first attempt I misspelt "ns2:Field", and a trace like this quickly sorted me out:

```
array{trace(?*?('ns2:field'))?*[?('$')?name='dID']?_}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is some odd format but it looks as if

```
  <xsl:output method="json"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="json-xml" select="json-to-xml($json)"/>
     <xsl:variable name="array" 
       select="array { 
                 $json-xml/array/map/array[@key = 'ns2:Field']/map[map[@key = '$'][string[@key = 'name'] = 'dID']]/string[@key = '_']/number() }"/>
     <xsl:sequence select="$array"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4ui gives the result `[138045,138078,138085]`.

Or you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match=".">
    <xsl:sequence select="array { ?*!.('ns2:Field')?*[.('$')?name = 'dID']('_')!number() }"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

if you make the result of `parse-json($json)` the inital match selection.